# How do I decode the response from an http request and use the content in netty?

Tags: java, netty

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693158/simple-way-to-use-netty-to-build-an-http-proxy-server), but I'm trying to break my problem into smaller steps.

I'm trying to write a simple http server (server A) using netty that receives an http request, makes an http request to another server (server B), and then copies the content in the response into the response to the initial request. I know there are some examples of how to do this, such as LittleProxy, but the code is fairly complex, and since I'm a n00b to netty, I'm trying to make my first code as simple as possible without getting off into the weeds.

For now, I'm ignoring all concerns about concurrency, and only have one channel established from server A to server B (I know this will break horribly with concurrent requests, but it makes my initial task simpler).

My approach is the following:

1. Set up client bootstrap and connect to server B running on localhost port 18080. Get the corresponding channel.
2. Start server A listening on port 2080 with a pipeline that decodes the http request and then writes to the channel going to server B.
3. Add a listener to the resulting channel future that will copy the content of the response from server B to the response to the original client's request to server A.

Here's the code I have (very short) in which I'm trying to do exactly what I describe above. My problem is that I don't know how to copy the response from server B to the response from server. The one way I have figured out to do this results in an IllegalArgumentException when I write to the original client in the response sent by server A (I checked the content of the ChannelBuffer, and the correct text was returned by the proxied server). I have pasted a partial stack trace of the exception below. Other comments welcome, as there may be other mistakes I'm making besides the obvious lack of locking on the channel to server B:

```
public class NettyExample {

private static Channel channel;
private static Map<Channel, Channel> proxyToClient = new ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, Channel>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChannelFactory clientFactory =
            new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    final ClientBootstrap cb = new ClientBootstrap(clientFactory);
    cb.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
            return Channels.pipeline(
                    new HttpRequestEncoder(),
                    new HttpResponseDecoder(),
                    new ResponseHandler());
        }
    });
    ChannelFuture cf = cb.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 18080));
    channel = cf.awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();

    ChannelFactory factory =
            new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    ServerBootstrap sb = new ServerBootstrap(factory);

    sb.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
            return Channels.pipeline(
                    new HttpRequestDecoder(),
                    new RequestHandler());
        }
    });

    sb.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    sb.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);

    sb.bind(new InetSocketAddress(2080));
}

private static class ResponseHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) {
        final HttpResponse proxyResponse = (HttpResponse) e.getMessage();
        Channel clientChannel = proxyToClient.get(e.getChannel());
        HttpResponse clientResponse = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
        clientResponse.setContent(proxyResponse.getContent());
        clientChannel.write(clientResponse).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                Channel ch = future.getChannel();
                ch.close();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        Channel ch = e.getChannel();
        ch.close();
    }
}

private static class RequestHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) {
        final HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();
        System.out.println("calling client channel");
        proxyToClient.put(channel, e.getChannel());
        channel.write(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        Channel ch = e.getChannel();
        ch.close();
    }
}
}
```

This relay call seems to work, up to the point of calling clientChannel.write(clientResponse). There, the following exception is generated:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported message type: class org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpResponse
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SocketSendBufferPool.acquire(SocketSendBufferPool.java:53)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.write0(AbstractNioWorker.java:468)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromTaskLoop(AbstractNioWorker.java:432)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup a client pipeline to wait for the response and then write it as your response.

See the snoop client [example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/snoop); specifically, [HttpSnoopClientHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClientHandler.java).

Comment: Thanks! I still have a problem with writing a DefaultHttpResponse to a channel. I'm not sure why it's not working in my case. I've edited the problem above to reflect this, and asked a separate question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795061/unable-to-write-defaulthttpresponse-to-a-channel-in-netty-unsupported-message) specifically about this.